# How to import class instead of module using __import__

Tags: python, import

I am writting script (main_script.py) which should import classes from certain modules found in the following directories:

```
main_script.py
    module1/
        __init__.py
        module1.py
```

The __ init __ .py files contain the following:

```
from module1.module1 import Module1
```

The module1.py contains a class Module1. The exact same architecture is followed for module 2.

```
    module2/
        __init__.py
        module2.py
```

The `main_script.py` should be able to import the classes `Module1` or `Module2` based on some conditionals.

Inside the main_script.py:

```
module_list=['module1.module1', 'module2.module2']

for module in module_list:
    if some_condition:
        mod = __import__(module)
        class_ = getattr(mod, module.split(".")[1])
        setattr(self, m1, class_)
```

I found out that instead of the classes, it only imports the modules. Can somebody set me on the right track?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it:

1) I adopted eqperes's remark and used importlib. 
2) I realized that before setting the attribute, I have to create an instance of the class. So I added:

```
module_list = ['module1.module1', 'module2.module2']

for module in module_list:
    if some_condition:
        mod = importlib.import_module(module)

        # Don't forget to capitalize the name of the class!
        class_ = getattr(mod, module.split(".")[1].capitalize())

        # Don't forget to make an instance of the class!!
        c=class_()

        setattr(self, m1, c)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should avoid using `__import__` and use [importlib](https://docs.python.org/2/library/importlib.html#importlib.import_module) instead :

```
import importlib

module_list = ['module1.module1', 'module2.module2']

for module in module_list:
    if some_condition:
        mod = importlib.import_module(module)
        class_ = getattr(mod, module.split(".")[1].capitalize())
        # Don't forget to capitalize the name of the class!
        setattr(self, m1, class_)
```

Comment: The problem is that when I print the vars(_temp) I get:  mp dict_keys(['__doc__', '__version__', '__package__', '__spec__', 'serial', 'logging', '__file__', '__author__', '__name__', '__loader__', '__builtins__', 'Module1', 'logger', '__cached__'])     . This seems that the class is not imported. So I want to import Module1. I think that I am one step further though.

Comment: I think your comment is related to Omid's answer, isn't it?

Comment: Nope,I used your notation. _temp = importlib.import_module('module1.module1', package='Module1').

Answer (score 0):

You can do some thing like this:

```
    _temp = __import__('foo.bar', globals(), locals(), ['object'], -1) 
object = _temp.object
```

Also see [python docs](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#__import__)